# shortest distant of curve from origin

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

what'd be shortest distance of curve from origin(0,0) function is $$ y=\frac{e^x+ e^{-x}}{2} $$ 
I tried taking some x and y points on curve then using distance formula finding distant then i found differential coefficient and equated to zero $$ dS/dx =0 $$  but did't got my answer

Comment: It's worth noting that this is just the function y=cosh(x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function decreases on $(-\infty,0]$ and increases on $[0,\infty)$ and is everywhere positive.  That means as $x$ moves away from $0$, so does $y$.  It follows that the point on the graph closest to the origin is where $x=0$.  (And at that point, $y=1$.)

If you **must** do this by differentiating, then it's more efficient to minimze the **square** of the distance rather than the distance itself.  As the distance gets bigger, so does the square of the distance, so that gets you the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that in the point $P$ of minimal distance the line through $(0,0)$ and $P$ is normal to $y$.  Provided that $y'\neq0$, just solve 
$$-\frac{1}{y'}\cdot x=y$$
and treat the case $y'=0$ seperately.

That can be easily generalized to determine the minimal distance from $y$ to any other point than the origin

Michael